# How to retrieve only a row if row are same in web sql?

Tags: sql, html, web

```
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
```

How do I retrieve only a single row if row values are the same in web SQL?

Result:

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data really is just 1 column then use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT yourcolumn
FROM yourtable
```